# Can't print a self-made matrix outside of its module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 modules in my project:

1- Ant.py

```
from threading import Thread
from Ant_farm import Ant_farm

ant_farm = Ant_farm(20, 20)

class Ant(Thread):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        global ant_farm

        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        ant_farm.matrix[self.x][self.y] = True # At this point the arguments has initialized?


    def move(self, x, y):
        ant_farm.matrix[self.x][self.y] = False
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        ant_farm.matrix[self.x][self.y] = True  # At this point the value has changed?

    def run(self):
        while True:
            ant_farm.move_ant(self)

t = Ant(0, 0)
print(ant_farm[0][0])
t.move(1, 0)
```

2- Ant_farm.py

```
from threading import Condition

def matrix(x, y):
    return [[False for j in range(y)] for i in range(x)]

class Ant_farm():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.c = Condition()    # I don't know if I have to put "self" before
        self.matrix = matrix(x, y)

    def move_ant(self, ant):
        new_pos = {0: tuple(x0, y0 - 1),
                   1: tuple(x0 + 1, y0),
                   2: tuple(x0, y0 + 1),
                   3: tuple(x0 - 1, y0)}
        x0, y0 = ant.x, ant.y
        x1, y1 = new_pos[random.randrange(0, 4)]
        with self.c:
            try:
                while self.matrix[x1][y1]:
                    self.c.wait()
                self.matrix[x0][y0] = False
                ant.move(x1, y1)
                # It's not end and I have to review

            except Exception:   # Wich exceptions can appear?
                pass

    def __str__(self):
        pass
```

In both omit the comments.

When I execute the `Ant` module, raises this error:

> AttributeError: Ant_farm instance has no attribute '__getitem__'

in the line 27 (`print(ant_farm[0][0])`). Why does this?

Comment: Are you trying to get the content of `self.matrix` in `Ant_farm`? If so, you need to define method `__getitem__` in `Ant_farm` class or whatever method to return `self.matrix[x][y]`

Comment: Do you mean `print(ant_farm.matrix[0][0])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, you did not define what `ant_farm[i]` is (the function `__getitem__`).
You probably want something like this in your `Ant_farm` class:

```
def __getitem__(i):
    return self.matrix[i]
```